# Update children View Model from Parent raising events

Tags: c#, wpf, events, mvvm, backgroundworker

Class involved:

1. Classic MVVM as container for Children Controls.
2. Children Controls with their own View Model (Button to be specific).
3. BackgroundWorker polling via socket a remote host.

Behaviour:

- Main application starts loading Children Controls from an XML list.
  Every Child has and handler for an update event in the Parent View
  Model (we call it Main View Model) that updates a property of the
  Child.
- Main ViewModel starts a BackgroundWorker
- BackgroundWorker calls a Socket Method and uses a ViewModel Callback for the response.
- The Callback updates Main ViewModel properties.

Since here it works perfectly, but then:

- The updated property raises an event in the set and the Children handlers start with their own property update.
- While updating an exception is raised:

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

After few seconds the buttons update. I guess because the UI thread takes the control again and updates the controls. But, is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend Uebercoder's answer, you may not care about controls in your view model, but you still need to marshal the background updates onto the main thread.

So either in your background worker, or more likely in your main viewmodel, you need to do something like:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => { /* update properties */ } )));
```

Comment: Yes, thank you it's clear. But in my property set I raise an event and not a direct property update. Since it works for the parent view model, it's clear that the Event Handler in the Child view model needs to re-join the UI Thread. But, is there a better way to design it without the Dispatcher trick?

Comment: I would disagree that the child view models should need to care about marshaling. Yes, that is where it blows up because of the control access, but the main viewmodel is what knows about the background thread, so it should be in charge of marshaling. Consumers of your main viewmodel should not have to know about its implementation. The only other way to do this is have the main viewmodel poll the background thread, but that sort of negates the point of having it.

Comment: I mark this as answer because I'm currently using it and seems to be the quickest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Only the owning thread can update a window element (ie controls).

Use the `Control.Invoke()` method to make changes to the button. I have a little helper class that I wrote to take care of this.

```
public static class ControlEx
{
    public static void DoSafely(this Control control, Action action)
    {
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
            control.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    action();
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }));
        else
            action();
    }
}
```

So that instead of doing something like:

```
button.Text = "new text";
```

from the other thread, I now call

```
button.DoSafely(() => button.Text = "new text");
```

Comment: I'm in MVVM, I don't care about the Control because I'm updating a ViewModel property.

Comment: As GazTheDestroyer stated, whether you update a property on the control or a property in your model the idea is the same.

Comment: Indeed, but in this way I need to call each child view model, it's not acceptable. I have event subscription to avoid it.